# NPM not installing packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I have a project with dependencies in package.json.  When I install with `npm install`, I get packages installed in `~/.npm` but not in the current folder's `node_modules`.

NPM is creating `node_modules`, but not installing packages there.  There's a `.staging` folder within `node_modules`, which contains all of the packages for the projects, but they're not being moved out after retrieval.

Using Node v6.9.1 / npm v3.10.8.

There aren't any other projects/node_modules installed in directories higher than the current one, though there is a package.json in the parent directory as well.  No `node_modules` directory gets created in the parent directory, however.

Strangely enough, when I manually install a package like `npm install @angular/core` it installs without problem.

This is on Ubuntu 16.04.

package.json:

```
{ 
  "name": "", 
  "version": "0.5.0", 
  "description": "website (Angular2/NodeJS)", 
  "main": "main.js", 
  "scripts": { 
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" 
  }, 
  "author": "John Halbert <https://halbert.tech> (john@halbert.tech)", 
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.md", 
  "dependencies": { 
    "@angular/common": "^2.1.1", 
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.1.1", 
    "@angular/core": "^2.1.1", 
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.1", 
    "@angular/http": "^2.1.1", 
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.1", 
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.1", 
    "@angular/router": "^3.1.1", 
    "core-js": "^2.4.1", 
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8", 
    "systemjs": "^0.19.39", 
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26" 
  },
  "devDependencies": { 
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0", 
    "typings": "^1.4.0" 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Which `npm` flag are you using alongside `install` command?

Comment: No flags used for install.

Comment: Have you already tried to remove `node_modules` folder and reinstall needed packages?

Comment: Yes, I also cleared cached packages in `~/.npm` directory as well.

Comment: Can you provide your package.json file?

Comment: Posted package.json to original question.

Comment: is it ok to have the name field empty?

Comment: It's actually not, I just left it blank here. In the actual file it has a value.

Comment: Is the NPM running ok (returning 0 in bash)? Is there a `npm-debug.log`file in the root after it runs? If it does, post it here.

Comment: Node.js 6.9.1 is ancient and may not be compatibile with new packages. npm v3.10.8 is old too and that may cause problems with installing packages. To update npm, simply run `npm update -g npm` and for Node.js use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
echo "" > $(npm config get userconfig)
npm config edit
```

To see if you have change de node modules default folder, if so, you can reset the configurations by doing

```
echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)
npm config --global edit
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research it looks like this is a memory issue with my server.  Running on a low-end VPS with 128Mb RAM.

There are a few suggestions on how to deal with this.  I found others suggesting `npm config set jobs 1` as a way to limit memory usage, but this hasn't worked for me.  Others suggest adding (more) swap, which is disallowed by my hosting provider.

The npm process is actually being killed so it appears this is likely the culprit.